# An application of Zorn's Lemma in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace, cyclic-decomposition

> Let $\alpha$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$. Let $v_0\in V$ and suppose that the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ is $m_\alpha(x)$ and of $\alpha$ at $v_0$ is $m_{\alpha,\ v_0}(x)$. Suppose $m_\alpha(x)= m_{\alpha,\ v_0}(x)=[f(x)]^k$, for some monic irreducible $f(x)\in F[x]$.
>
> Using Zorn's Lemma, prove that there exists $W$, an invariant subspace of $V$, such that $V=\left<v_0\right>_\alpha\bigoplus W$

I tried to consider the set $P=\{\,W\mid \text{$W$ is invariant subspace of $V$ and $\left<v_0\right>_\alpha\bigoplus W$}\,\}$ but neither its non-emptiness nor the existence of an upper bound is clear to me. Can someone give me a hint on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You never defined the notation $m_\alpha$ or $m_{\alpha,v}$ and you don't explain what it means to say it equals the polynomial $f^k(x)$, or what $f^k(x)$ means ($k$th power? $k$th iterate)? I think this post should be substantially rewritten to makes its meaning much clearer: define your notation.

Comment: @KCd My mistake, I have edited it.

Comment: Is your vector space supposed to be finite dimensional? The notion of minimal polynomial requires this, but I've never needed to use Zorn's lemma in finite dimensional linear algebra.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You could have a particular $\alpha$ on an infinite dimensional vector space that happens to have a minimal polynomial, even though not every operator will in that setting, of course.

Comment: Non-emptiness is trivial: $W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ satisfies all desired conditions. The second condition will be easier to verify if you give it as $\langle v_0\rangle_{\alpha}\cap W = \{\mathbf{0}\}$. As usual in this kind of setting, consider the union of your chain.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I know that an endomorphism might just happen to satisfy an algebraic relation, but the question says "suppose that the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ is..." which suggests that having a minimal polynomial is not an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I actually read it as simply asserting that $\alpha$ has a minimal polynomial, with no implication about anything else. But mileage may vary, and your reading is not unreasonable.